# Angular get reference to element when clicked

Tags: angular, angular6, angular5, angular7

I need to get a reference to the angular component that is related to any element that I click on with my mouse in my Angular application.

IE: I click anywhere on the screen and I need to get a reference of the closest Angular component (that was created in my application, not node_modules) and it's internal variables. I figure I have to somehow query the Angular view tree to get this, but I am unsure of where to start or if this is even remotely possible.

What I tried?

```
export class XComponent implements OnInit {
    @HostListener('document:click', ['$event']) handleClick($event) {
        let clickedComponent: Node = $event.target;
        let inside: boolean = false;

        do {
            if ( clickedComponent.localName && clickedComponent.localName.substr( 0, 4 ) === "app-" ) {
                this.analyzeActiveNode( clickedComponent );
                break;
            }

            clickedComponent = clickedComponent.parentNode;
        } while (clickedComponent);
    }

    analyzeActiveNode( _node: Node ) {
        //Somehow get the component and preferrably it's THIS context, that relates to this _node
    }
}
```

In short, this code recursively travels the DOM tree, until it finds a DOM node thats selector starts with 'app-', which is pseudocode for my Angular component prefix. Then after I find this DOM node, I need to somehow get the Angular component reference out of it.

Bear in mind that the XComponent that I am listening to all of the clicks on, can live anywhere in the application, so using ViewChild/ViewChildren is not an option.

PS. This code is for educational purposes and I am not trying to adhere to Angular design patterns with it. It is not made for a production environment, but instead is used internally by our developers.

Comment: Have you looked into using the Augury Chrome extension? It does exactly what you are asking about. https://augury.rangle.io/

Comment: Thank you, yes I have. It's pretty decent, but we have a really complex application and I wanted to create a few proprietary debugging tools for ourselves, so I don't really want to get stuck with Augury. Great suggestion though!

Comment: Their code is open source on github. You may be able to look through that to see how they were able to do things. https://github.com/rangle/augury